# Why I don't see Swam Mode in Docker Cloud UI?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-cloud

This is how Docker Cloud UI looks to me:

[image]

Why there's no Swarm Mode toggle? What am I missing?

Comment: Docker swarm is currently in beta stage on docker cloud. check [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/cloud-swarm/)

Comment: I read that article, it says nothing on how to enable Swarm UI.

Comment: may be it's in limited public beta. So, may be we won't have access to it until it is released in a stable version.